# Calendar React Native ImageBackground

Tags: react-native

I want my calendar that has different logo for certain dates and no logo for others. At first it is fine, but when I change month, the ImageBackground image does not changes to null and just stays while adding the certain dates logo. How should I fix?

```
<RN.ImageBackground
                source={item == 5 ? require('../../assets/a_logo.png') :
                        item == 9 ? require('../../assets/b_logo.png') :
                        item == 14 ? require('../../assets/c_logo.png') :
                        item == 24 ? require('../../assets/d_logo.png') : null} />
```